# CORS support for dl.dropboxuserconent.com?

Tags: javascript, cors, dropbox-api

It seems that we can no longer [programmatically download content](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2013/08/programmatically-download-content-from-share-links/) from share links via JavaScript in the browser. Has the method changed?

When I try the following links, they no longer return with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header:

- https://www.dropbox.com/s/mrt5fei8gsndfqb/test.json?raw=1
- https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mrt5fei8gsndfqb/test.json

They used to have the correct CORS header. How are we supposed to download public content via JavaScript now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be working fine for me. Perhaps you can share the code you're using and the specific issue you're seeing:

```
$ curl -i https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mrt5fei8gsndfqb/test.json -H Origin:www.example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
accept-ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Accept-Ranges, Content-Range, X-Dropbox-Metadata, X-Dropbox-Request-Id, X-JSON, X-Server-Response-Time
Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
cache-control: max-age=0
content-disposition: inline; filename="test.json"; filename*=UTF-8''test.json
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 07 Mar 2015 20:43:09 GMT
etag: 384005n
pragma: public
Server: nginx
set-cookie: uc_session=7OdIkBHxIyByXccQK7zTrCJxlvuEZEThdbehLwKo2eaQTiaxETBhvI0yS8wrNt3H; Domain=dropboxusercontent.com; Path=/; secure; httponly
x-dropbox-request-id: 7bf5833588818b70adca21e463ce77d9
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow, noimageindex
x-server-response-time: 170
Content-Length: 18
Connection: keep-alive

{"success": true}
```

Comment: Interesting! If you don't have an `Origin:` header, there's no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:` header in the response.

Comment: I believe that's typical of CORS.

Comment: I just passed the `Origin` header and this worked perfectly fine. Thanks :)